# When calling function with function arguments inside the class, field is not accessible inside these functions. Why?

Tags: javascript

```js
class Field1 {
  data = 0;
  constructor(init) {
    this.data = init;
  }
}

class Field2 {
  data = 0;
  constructor(init) {
    this.data = init;
  }
}

class Field3 {
  data = 0;
  constructor(init) {
    this.data = init;
  }
}

class Test {
  field1 = new Field1(1);
  field2 = new Field2(2);
  field3 = new Field3(3);

  constructor() {
    this.compose2(this.func1, this.func2, this.func3);
  }

  func1() {
    console.log("init func1");
    console.log(this.field1.data);
  }
  func2() {
    console.log("init func2");
    console.log(this.field2.data);
  }
  func3() {
    console.log("init func3");
    console.log(this.field3.data);
  }
  compose2(...args) {
    console.log(args);

    args.reduce(
      (prevFunc, nextFunc) => {
        nextFunc();
      },
      (init) => init
    );
  }
}

new Test();
```

Inside the func1, func2, func3 functions, class fields named field1, field2, field3 is not accessible.
I get error message saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field1')". I assume it is because Class syntax. Because it works find without class.

Comment: Why did you create 3 classes with the same code? Use a single `Field` class and instantiate it thrice!

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `this` context, which can be done with [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```js
nextFunc.call(this);
```